# Reading the content with html tags from JSON file and displaying in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I have JSON file which holds labels and content to display in my mobile application.

I am using $.getJSON to read the JSON file locally in my project. It will return the JSON object. Using that object i am displaying the labels/text content in Javascript. While displaying the content with html characters it is not loading properly, still its show html characters.

Content inside JSON

```
 "CONSENT_EMAIL_REQUEST_BODY"  :   "Please read the below content <br> Welcome to the project <br> you can now use the application."
```

If i try to print the value of CONSENT_EMAIL_REQUEST_BODY in javascript it still displaying

```
  Please read the below content <br> Welcome to the project <br> you can now use the application.
```

It is not displaying line by line the break
 are displaying as it is. How to replace these html characters to display properly in mobile/browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Before printing, You have to replace line break 
 with '\n'.

Suppose if you take your content to a variable mycontent then you can do it as:

```
mycontent = mycontent.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/mg,"\n");
```

Then print mycontent. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me with the following code:

```
var json =  jQuery.parseJSON( '{"CONSENT_EMAIL_REQUEST_BODY"  :   "Please read the below content <br> Welcome to the project <br> you can now use the application."}');

$("span").html(json.CONSENT_EMAIL_REQUEST_BODY);
```

Maybe are you using `.text()` instead of `.html()` ?

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lparcerisa/q3hmjg7w/